# ¿Se pueden usar los controles del toolbox Visual Studio, como el GridView, UpdatePanel, AjaxControl Toolkit, etc trabajando con MVC y Razor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estoy trabajando con `visual studio 2013` con `MVC` y `razor`, pero me gustaría aprovechar de usar los controles de visual studio, como `gridview`, `treeview`, `navigator`, etc.

Recuerdo que cuando trabajé en visual studio 2010 con capas y `WCF` podía utilizar las herramientas de toolbox, pero en este caso que les planteo, creo que no se puede, si alguien me sabe, me dice por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me temo que no, los WebControl ya no estas disponibles en asp.net mvc, mas que nada porque cambio toda la arquitectura. Imagino conoces que conceptos como eventos, viewstate ya no existen.

Pero tienes equivalente, por ejemplo para el `GridView` tiene el [WebGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid(v=vs.111).aspx)

[WebGrid en MVC 3, paso a paso](http://www.variablenotfound.com/2011/02/webgrid-en-mvc-3-paso-paso.html)

Para reemplazar el `UpdatePanel` tiene el [Ajax.BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

[Working With Html.BeginForm() and Ajax.BeginForm() in MVC 3](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/working-with-html-beginform-and-ajax-beginform-in-mvc-3/)

La idea es que uses Helpers de mvc que rendericen el html en la view